# How to edit a post for source code highlighting?

Tags: support

In reference to this question: [How to make java wait for user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678950/how-to-make-java-wait-for-user-input)

Apparently, it was unknown or forgot to add 4 spaces before the first line. Which makes the source code unreadable because there are no linebreaks anymore.

If I try to edit the post and add the 4 whitespaces, it looks like i cannot do it:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>   Edits must be at least 6 non-space characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

What to do at this point?

Comment: Actually it works with me, I only add 4 extra spaces, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678950/how-to-make-java-wait-for-user-input

Comment: @JW. The 6 non-space character limit only applies to users without full editing privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently have less than 2000 rep on StackOverflow, which means all your suggested edits are reviewed. We discourage people from making minor edits because each one is reviewed by multiple users with >2000 rep.

Two options:

1. Leave it - someone else will hopefully notice, but better is:
2. Look carefully for something that can be phrased better, some spelling mistakes or other problems, and make those edits too. Fixing *all* the issues in a post is very much welcomed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. Then I will just ignore all malformatted posts. I do not intend to make pointless edits just because to have enough characters for some rules.

Comment: @tb If there's a lot of malformatted code, that would be a good, valid and valued edit, but if it's just a little, you'll need to wait until you have more rep.